# Is there a standard symbol for gain margin?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, control-system, feedback

In the context of control loops, specifically power supply control loops in my case, the symbol \$\phi_m\$ is used for phase margin. I've occasionally seen it with a capital M, but on balance it seems to be pretty consistently the lower case subscript.

My question is: *Is there also a standard symbol for gain margin?* Like perhaps \$A_m\$ or \$G_m\$? I searched around and could only find instances where it was actually spelled out; of course that could be because I could only search on "gain margin", not knowing exactly what to be looking for :)

It's come up as a value to be stated in my last couple of questions and I wanted to avoid using a phrase if a nice compact symbol would do the needful :)

Comment: "Gain" is not unambiguous. You should probably specify the unit being gained if you don't mean power.

Comment: Ah good point, thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I'll add a bit more context ... :)

Comment: Also known as critical gain, Kcrit, Kc

Comment: GM and PM are used quite widely for gain and phase margins. I don't think there's a 'standard'.

Comment: I agreee to Chu`s answer. More than that, each good text (article) should use symbols only in conjunction with a corresponding explanation. Otherwise, misinterpretations cannot be avoided. Negative example: "The SR of an opamp is a very important parameter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, and on the new sensitivity to the topic I always get from submitting a StackExchange question, I believe the best answer is: \$GM\$

I've noticed this usage several times since reading the comments I received in response, and have encountered no alternative symbols or abbreviations.

I have noticed a tendency for it to appear with \$PM\$ as the expression for phase margin, as @Chu mentioned, and definitely agree with @LvW's remark that good practice is to introduce the symbol the first time it's used, as in: *... the gain margin (\$GM\$) of the circuit is 27dB.*

So I'm mourning the loss of a perfectly good opportunity to use a fancy Greek letter in my technical writing, but I suppose I'll have to get over it :)